# Pass data from jQuery.ajax() to angular controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I have the following javascript file called `script.js` with a jQuery function:

```
function getData(a, b) {

var d = [];

while (a <= b)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "someurl",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            d.push(data.rates);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    a+=1;
}

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    console.log("AJAX STOP");
    return d;
}); }
```

**Explanation**:
I fill the array `d` in a while loop with some information I get as a response from server `someurl`. I would like to pass this array to my controller called `MainController.js`. How do I do this? I would like to have a property in my controller, for example $scope.dataFromAjax, and it has to be equal to the final form of array `d` from ajax(). 
(something like `$scope.dataFromAjax = d`). 
Thank you.

Comment: Is there a really compelling reason why you can't simply write this into an angular service utilizing `$http`?

Comment: not at all, I've been more familar with jQuery. can you please write me a short sample on how to do this?

Comment: There are plenty of examples on how to use the `$http` service in AngularJS, not the least of which is the [AngularJS documentation for the service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Generally, you'll be hard-pressed to find a good use case for having jQuery + AngularJS unless you need to support legacy code. [Check out this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Angular's $http you can have a service that gets the data for you which you can inject into any controller, factory, directive, etc that you need to access your data.

```
app.service('dataService', ['$http', function ($http) {
  return {
    getSomething: function () {
      return $http.get('someurl');
    },
    getSomethingElse: function () {
      return $http.get('someotherurl');
    }
  }
}]);

app.controller("yourController", ['$scope', 'dataService', function ($scope, dataService) {
  dataService.getSomething().success(function(dataResults) {
    $scope.data = dataResults; // This is available as soon as the promise (get) is resolved.
  });
}]);
```